# Passing ViewModel into and out of a form via Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table form where users can enter a few fields that correspond to a `Schedule` model. They can also select a `User` from a dropdown for that `Schedule`. To send all the required data to the View, I have a `ViewModel` that contains one `Schedule` and one `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` containing all the users in the system.

In my controller, I create a `List` of `SchedulingViewModels`. I then pass the `List<SchedulingViewModel>` to a PartialView (I've included only the relevant parts):

```
@model List<JNEScheduling.Models.SchedulingViewModel>

...

<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].schedule.UserID, Model[i].users)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].schedule.hours)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].schedule.week_ending)
         </td>
         </tr>
  }
   <tr>
</tbody>
```

Then I load the PartialView into my View via Ajax. The loading works fine. However, when the form is `POST`ed, it passes a list of empty `Schedule` objects to the Controller, not a list of populated `SchedulingViewModel` objects, as expected.

I believe it has to do with the DOM names of all the inputs on the form; they take the form of `[index].schedule.hours` etc. **How do I pass back the list of Scheduling View Model objects?** Or even a populated `List` of `Schedule` objects would be fine.

The Jquery for the `POST`:

```
 $('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var content = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Table", "Schedule")',
        data: content,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#hoursTable').html(data);
    }
});
```

*Update*:
One row of the table generated by the Ajax `GET` from the `PartialView`, after using Brian's `SchedulingContainerViewModel`. I've removed the validation tags generated by the `@Html` methods:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="Items[0].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <select name="Items[0].schedule.UserID">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">User 1</option>
            <option value="2">User 2</option>
            <option value="3">User 3</option>
            <option value="4">User 4</option>
            <option value="5">User 5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="Items[0].schedule.hours" type="text" value="40.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
            <input name="Items[0].schedule.week_ending" type="text" value="5/26/2017 12:00:00 AM" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Update 2*: The XHR data being passed back:[image: XHR Data for Ajax POST]

Comment: I've updated the OP

Comment: Sorry, I only included one `tbody tr` for brevity. The whole thing is in a valid table with `form` tags around.

Comment: @BrianMains answer fixed the weird DOM names, but there is now no call to the controller altogether.

Comment: Updated. The XHR request is now fine; returns 200, and there is a call to the controller. Just the data it's sending is a null `List<SchedulingViewModel>`.

Comment: Inspect your network request that is being sent to look at the request data (usually at the bottom or maybe even in a preview tab).  From what knowledge i have about applications auto mapping inputs to classes, you'll need to make sure the naming structure on the inputs being passed match those on your SchedulingViewModel, or else it won't know where to stick stuff.  @brian-mains might know more about that though.

Comment: Alright, I found that each `SchedulingViewModel` had an ID of 0, so I manually gave each one an ID when they're being created and loaded into `SchedulingContainerViewModel`. That didn't make any difference though... @Brian?

Comment: You need to show your models and the signature for the POST method! (we cannot possible guess what your `name` attributes need to be in order to bind)

Answer (score 1):

The naming structure looks right.  SOmetimes, rather than use a list, I add a wrapper class like:

```
public class ScheduleContainerViewModel
{
   public List<SchedulingViewModel> Items { get; set;}
}
```

which would render:

```
Items[index].schedule.hours
```

I use this approach and it works in my projects.

Comment: Thanks! The `List<SchedulingViewModel>` is being passed to the controller `POST` method now, but the list is empty. The DOM names now are `Items[index].schedule.hours`, like you said. The Ajax has remained the same. Any advice?